# Django testcase without database migrations and syncdb

Tags: python, django, django-testing, django-migrations

I am trying to create test cases for my migration functions (called with `migrations.RunPython`). My idea was to create a test case that doesn’t run migrations before starting, neither syncdb to create the database in one step. After this, I’m planning to run the first step, run associated tests, run the second step then its associated tests, etc. Is this possible somehow, or if not, is it possible to test migration functions in any way?

Comment: Is it really usefull? When you use a TestCase all the migrations are run one by one (at least my coverage reports seem to indicate that)

Comment: If you tell me another way to test my migration functions, I can go on with that (after all, that’s why I added my use case). Coverage output says that my migration functions are not covered; that’s because there is no data to run them on.

Comment: FAIK not having data is not an issue. It's still get's covered. My migrations files are some of the few things that show 100% coverage :-)

Comment: Do you use `RunPython`?

Comment: Yes, I do have one migration with RunPython where some triggers are created by using custom sql. just ran those tests. 100% coverage for that file. What's the bet that you are running your tests with the -k option

Comment: My `RunPython` migrations do something like `for user in User.objects.all(): user.settings.whatever = x`. However, if I don’t have users (which I don’t, in case of a freshly created database), this `for` won’t run.

Answer (score 1):

When you use django's `TestCase`, it has an explicit requirement that the database must be setup, which means all migrations must be applied. If you want to test things without the migrations happening, you cannot use `TestCase`.

Use a testing toolkit that doesn't depend on django, like `pytest` and write your own code to test. You can always import django models and settings explicitly.

Your tests would first run the explicit tests where database is not created, after which, the other tests can be run containing `TestCase`.

I'm not sure whether such a setup is possible with `manage.py`, but you can certainly create your own script (maybe using `fabric` or plain `python`) to run tests in your choice of order.

Comment: This actually gave me an idea of overriding `TestCase` (or more likely, `TransactionTestCase`. I already did the same in another project where I wanted to skip database creation/handling at all. This way I will have to create the database myself, and running the migrations step by step (I hope). I will come back with the result soon(ish).

Comment: Why handle all the work yourself when it's already being handled quite elegantly by `TestCase` ?

Comment: What I meant, was, why _repeat_ the code instead of extending it by creating external tests for migrations and _then_ calling the django test runs?